# Representation of int in memory

Tags: c, memory, language-lawyer, endianness

On architectures where `int` is represented using multiple bytes in memory, what constraints does the C Standard impose regarding possible representations? Most current systems use either little-endian or big-endian representations, but it is possible to have a conforming system with a different representation? How different can it be?

Comment: On some DSP, you find 40 bits registers. In the old days, I worked on an IBM machine where the word length was 72 bits, whatever the data type (so technically this might have been called a byte, I guess).

Comment: I believe that big/little-endian and number of bits are implementation defined and transparent to the C compiler. Possible exception is requirements by the language about the numeric range of integers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: could you name such a DSP still selling in 2020 ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: no. Does that matter ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, second hand or from museum?

Comment: This was historical curiosity. I am old enough to have coded (in 1974, as a teenager) on punched cards (IBM 370/168; PL/1), and even on CAB500 and IBM1620 (in Palais de la Découverte museum of Paris). But my question is about *existing* DSP in 2020

Comment: "*On architectures where `int` is represented using multiple bytes in memory*" - Isn't that always the case? The C standard mandates an `int` needs be able to represent at least −32767 to +32767, as Eric also mentioned in his last paragraph. Do you include 16 bit (including sign bit) - byte `int`s here?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: it is not always the case: on systems where bytes have at least 16 bits, `int` could be stored in a single byte and `sizeof(int)` would be `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what constraints does the C Standard impose regarding possible representations?

3 Encodings allowed: 2's complement, 1s' complement, sign-magnitude.  Non-2's complement could have either a -0 or a trap representation.

`int` must be 16-bit or wider (a range of at *least* [-32767...32767]).  Could be 36 or 64 for real historic examples.

> but it is possible to have a conforming system with a different representation?

**Sample: [PDP-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#PDP-endian)**

0x01020304 stored as 2, 1, 4, 3.  See also [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970091/representation-of-int-in-memory/62970189#comment111355837_62970189).

> How different can it be?

`int` may have padding, `char` cannot.  I do not know of any `int` with padding.

`int` could be 1 "byte" when a "byte" is more than 16 bits.
IIRC, some graphics processors used 64-bit "byte", `char`, `int`, `long`, `long long`.

I once did used a 64-bit `long, unsigned long` where the `unsigned long` had 1 padding bit such that `ULONG_MAX == LONG_MAX`.  Compliant but unusual.  In theory, `UINT_MAX == INT_MAX` is possible - never heard of such an implementation.

In 2020, I suspect the follow are universal.

- Endian: either big or little.
- 2's complement. (Next C might require this.)
- "byte size" of 8 (*maybe* 16, 32), `int` is 16 or 32 bit.
- No padding.

Comment: Thank you @chux, incidentally the PDP-endian representation was for 32-bit longs and did not correspond to a hardware implementation, but rather a compiler specific choice for reading/storing values with 2 instructions into/from 2 registers.

Answer (score 2):

From the following citations from the standard, we see:

- `int` has at least 16 bits.
- Any ordering of bytes is permissible.
- Any ordering of bits is permissible (but must match `unsigned int`).
- The value bits are binary.
- Negative values use one of the three specified methods.

C 2018 6.2.6.1 says:

> 1 The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.

> 2 Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.

> 4 Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type [other than unsigned bit-fields and `unsigned char`, addressed in paragraph 3] consist of *n* × `CHAR_BIT` bits, where *n* is the size of an object of that type, in bytes…

6.2.6.2 says:

> 1 For unsigned integer types other than `unsigned char`,… If there are *N* value bits, each bit shall represent a different power of 2 between 1 and 2<sup>*N*-1</sup>, so that objects of that type shall be capable of representing values from 0 to 2<sup>*N*</sup> − 1 using a pure binary representation;…

> 2 For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits; `signed char` shall not have any padding bits. There shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are *M* value bits in the signed type and *N* in the unsigned type, then *M* ≤ *N* ). If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the following ways:
>
> — the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (*sign and magnitude*);
>
> — the sign bit has the value −(2<sup>M</sup> ) (*two’s complement*);
>
> — the sign bit has the value −(2<sup>M</sup> − 1) (*ones’ complement*).
>
> Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones’ complement), is a trap representation or a normal value. In the case of sign and magnitude and ones’ complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a *negative zero*.

> 5 The values of any padding bits are unspecified… For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type.

And 5.2.4.2.1 tells us `int` must be able to represent at least −32767 to +32767, from which we deduce it has at least 15 value bits.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to use a different bit order for `int` and `unsigned char`? or even to use a scrambled representation where the value read from memory as an `int` cannot be easily determined from the individual bytes that compose it?